# Spring REST controller post request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I have this controller in spring

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greeting(@RequestParam("uouo") String uouo) {
        return uouo;
    }
}
```

and when I testing it

```
 curl -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d uouo=test http://192.168.1.104:8080/api/greeting
```

the result of the testing

HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'uouo' is not present

I tried may thing, but I think `@RequestParam` can't use for POST it always passed the parameter in URL using GET, I use post only if I had object JSON as parameter using `@RequestBody`, is there any way to make string parameter send using POST?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Servlet container will only provide parameters from the body for POST requests if the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It will ignore the body if the content type is anything else. This is specified in the [Servlet Specification Chapter 3.1.1 When Parameters Are Available](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

> The following are the conditions that must be met before post form
>   data will be populated to the parameter set:
>
> 1. The request is an HTTP or HTTPS request.
> 2. The HTTP method is POST.
> 3. The content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
> 4. The servlet has made an initial call of any of the `getParameter` family of methods on the request object.
>
> If the conditions are not met and the post form data is not included
>   in the parameter set, the post data must still be available to the
>   servlet via the request object’s input stream. If the conditions are
>   met, post form data will no longer be available for reading directly
>   from the request object’s input stream.

Since you aren't sending any JSON, just set the appropriate content type

```
curl -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d uouo=test http://192.168.1.104:8080/api/greeting
```

or let `curl` infer it

```
curl -k -i -X POST -d uouo=test http://192.168.1.104:8080/api/greeting?uouo=test
```

Note that you can still pass query parameters in the URL

```
curl -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://192.168.1.104:8080/api/greeting?uouo=test
```